# Java static initialization behaviour

Tags: java, static

```
public class Hello {
        public static final Hello h = new Hello();
        static int i = 5;
        int j  = i;

        private void print() {
            System.out.println(i+" , "+j);

        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            h.print();
        }

    }
```

This code output is 5 , 0.
if reason is static loads first in class and i is initialized and j is not.but if i remove static from i also

```
public class Hello {
        public static final Hello h = new Hello();
        int i = 5;
        int j  = i;

        private void print() {
            System.out.println(i+" , "+j);

        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            h.print();
        }

    }
```

now why output is 5,5. then when i and j is initialized.
please explain the reason.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The static block is executed in order.

You first create a Hello object, at this point `i = 0` as it hasn't been set.

Only after this does `i = 5`

You have to read the static statements from top to bottom.

Answer (score 5):

Non-static variables `i` and `j` are initialized that moment when `Hello` object is created:

```
public static final Hello h = new Hello();
```

For the first part of the question [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17234115/1256583) gave you an answer. Let me complement it. If you changed the order of static variables:

```
static int i = 5;
public static final Hello h = new Hello();
int j  = i;
```

it would print `5, 5` and not `5, 0`.

Comment: but in previous case ,why j was not initialized ,its value is 0.

Answer (score 2):

Try to swap the `public static final Hello h = new Hello();` and `static int i = 5;` lines.
You initialize first the `hello` object `(when i = 0, uninitialized)` and than `i`. Init the `i` first to get an expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what happens in your first example:

- Static memory is initialized to 0. At this point `Hello.i` equals 0.
- `Hello.h` is instantiated:

  - `Hello.h.j` is initialized to `Hello.i`'s current value, i.e. 0.
- `Hello.i` is initialized to 5.

In your second example, on the other hand:

- `Hello.h` is instantiated:

  - `Hello.h.i` is initialized to 5.
  - `Hello.h.j` is initialized to `Hello.h.i`'s current value, i.e. 5.

Answer (score 1):

Peter Lawrey's answer is correct, your confusion may be coming from the fact everything is in a single class and the names are like so i wanted to give you another way to visualize what your doing, so your code is logically equivalent to the following code:

```
public class Program {

    public static Hello h = new Hello();

        public static void main(String [] args) {
            h.i = 5;
            h.print();
        }
    }

    class Hello {

        public static int i = 0;
        private int j = i;

        public void print() {
            System.out.println(i+", "+j);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java does static initialization at the time of class loading. Therefore

```
public static final Hello h = new Hello();
```

creates an object with *i = 5* and default value of *j* when the *Hello* class is loaded.

If you make both the variables *i* and *j* non static members, both will have default values for the *static object h* .

If you create a a new object in your main method

```
Hello helloObj = new Hello();
```

It will give your the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

[From docs of oracle specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6)

> A static initializer declared in a class is executed when the class is initialized (§12.4.2). Together with any field initializers for class variables (§8.3.2), static initializers may be used to initialize the class variables of the class.